# Using OpenCV Old Interface with OpenCV4 Library

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an old C++ project which uses OpenCV 2.4.9, but I need to use some features from OpenCV4, so I want to upgrade My OpenCV library to version 4.

I don't want to change the old existing code. So, is there a way to upgrade to OpenCV4 but still using old OpenCV 2.4.9 interface?

**cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2** and **cv::MSER** are used which their interfaces have changed.

Comment: It depends which methods of the interface you actually use, and whether they are availabe in the new version.

Comment: Some methods and interfaces which are used have changed. But if possible I still want to use the old interface. @wohlstad

Comment: If the new version does not have the specific API that you need, I don't think you can use the old interface. Some old APIs are kept in newer versions for backwards compatibility, but if your isn't, there not much you can do except adapt your code to the new interface.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you won't get the C API anymore, if you mean that. you'll only get the C++ API, and there are no versions to that. you get the one API that's given by the version of the library you chose. things have changed a little since v2.x so you'll have to adapt your code where needed. your question is vague. please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz As you can see in case of cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 and cv::MSER, they have  C++ interface, but the interface and usage has changed in OpenCV4.